# Refresh Cloudfront distribution from an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I created an Amazon S3 bucket with Angular compiled files. Then I make a Cloudfront distribution linked with static files. The configuration is working fine with Angular code but now I need to make new version of the Angular code? What is the proper way to update the Angular code?

The solution for now that I found working in to delete the Amazon 3S bucket and start over again. Can you advise?

Comment: In the CloudFront, head over to the "Invalidations" tab and remove the cache after updating your code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!